# Microsoft Graph API: Teams App - Problem with "List members of a channel" using "team id"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a Teams App with a bot and am attempting to use Microsoft Graph API to retrieve all the members of a channel conversation.

According to the Microsoft Doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the GET URL is...

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/members
```

When I send a bot mention in the channel, it provides an event context dictionary which includes a "channelData" param like the below (slightly redacted with "X"):

```
  channelData: {
    teamsChannelId: '19:9b9d91fb85ec4146972XXXXXXXXXXXXX.tacv2',
    teamsTeamId: '19:B9zDXPWNaGn03wB8iifYw6XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@thread.tacv2',
    channel: { id: '19:9b9d91fb85ec414XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXa@thread.tacv2' },
    team: {
      id: '19:B9zDXPWNaGn03wB8iifYw6XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@thread.tacv2'
    },
    tenant: { id: 'b06932a5-6eed-4e9a-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX' }
```

However, when I make a call to the GET endpoint with teams-id = team{id} or tenant{id} and channel-id = channel{id} it returns the following:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "No Team found with Group id: b06932a5-6eed-4e9a-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "No Team found with Group id: b06932a5-6eed-4e9a-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
            "code": "ItemNotFound",
            "innerError": {},
            "date": "2022-05-30T21:13:42",
            "request-id": "d8e2dfc5-0410-422b-b79d-96b73f38196b",
            "client-request-id": "d8e2dfc5-0410-422b-b79d-96b73f38196b"
        }
    }
}
```

I think what the API really wants is team-id = "groupID" because when I go into the Teams Desktop app and "Get link to channel" it gives me the following...

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3a3ca3a04e49c447XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXthread.tacv2/Test%2520Channel%25201?groupId=8325270c-856a-4271-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&tenantId=b06932a5-6eed-4e9a-XXXX-XXXXXXXX
```

...and then if I use the "groupId" in the same GET call, it gives the expected response where all the members of the conversation are listed.

Now, this would be totally fine except...**I can't fine the "groupId" anywhere in the bot message turn context**...even on the "onMembersAdded" event which occurs when the bot is first added.

I've read every article / forum listing I can find on this, but so far am completely stumped...hopefully I'm missing something simple that someone can point out!

Comment: From the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) looks like you should try url encoding for the ids.

Comment: Could you please refer this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/team-chat-member-api-changes) if it helps you in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally figured this out...the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context) shows how to get additional context for the bot.

You have to call the TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext) to retrieve the aadGroupID:

```
export class MyBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
            const teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext);
            if (teamDetails) {
                await turnContext.sendActivity(`The group ID is: ${teamDetails.aadGroupId}`);
            } else {
                await turnContext.sendActivity('This message did not come from a channel in a team.');
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}
```